# fragments class unable to start activity componentinfo

Tags: android, android-fragments

I wanted to learn Fragment. So started to learning from [tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm).
The Example was:

> This example will explain you how to create your own Fragments. Here
>   we will create two fragments and one of them will be used when device
>   is in landscape mode and another fragment will be used in case of
>   portrait mode.

When I runned application occurred this Exception:

```
04-08 10:57:20.135  19408-19408/net.motameni.apps.fragments D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-08 10:57:20.137  19408-19408/net.motameni.apps.fragments E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: net.motameni.apps.fragments, PID: 19408
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.motameni.apps.fragments/net.motameni.apps.fragments.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at net.motameni.apps.fragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.isSupportFragmentClass(Fragment.java:454)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2123)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreateView(ActionBarActivity.java:547)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at net.motameni.apps.fragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-08 12:49:45.078  26843-26843/net.motameni.apps.fragments I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-08 12:49:45.445  26843-26843/net.motameni.apps.fragments D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-08 12:49:45.452  26843-26843/net.motameni.apps.fragments E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: net.motameni.apps.fragments, PID: 26843
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.motameni.apps.fragments/net.motameni.apps.fragments.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at net.motameni.apps.fragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment net.motameni.apps.fragments.Raw_Fragment did not create a view.
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2145)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5282)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at net.motameni.apps.fragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-08 12:49:50.902  26843-26843/net.motameni.apps.fragments I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 26843 SIG: 9
04-08 13:20:18.838  30365-30365/net.motameni.apps.fragments I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-08 13:20:19.081  30365-30384/net.motameni.apps.fragments D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
04-08 13:20:19.091  30365-30365/net.motameni.apps.fragments D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
04-08 13:20:19.138  30365-30384/net.motameni.apps.fragments I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/28/14, c33033c, Ia6306ec328
04-08 13:20:19.139  30365-30384/net.motameni.apps.fragments I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-08 13:20:19.159  30365-30384/net.motameni.apps.fragments D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-08 13:20:41.066  31240-31260/net.motameni.apps.fragments D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
04-08 13:20:41.072  31240-31240/net.motameni.apps.fragments D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
04-08 13:20:41.114  31240-31260/net.motameni.apps.fragments I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/28/14, c33033c, Ia6306ec328
04-08 13:20:41.115  31240-31260/net.motameni.apps.fragments I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-08 13:20:41.135  31240-31260/net.motameni.apps.fragments D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-08 13:21:02.984  32157-32207/net.motameni.apps.fragments D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
04-08 13:21:02.992  32157-32157/net.motameni.apps.fragments D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
04-08 13:21:03.031  32157-32207/net.motameni.apps.fragments I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/28/14, c33033c, Ia6306ec328
04-08 13:21:03.032  32157-32207/net.motameni.apps.fragments I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-08 13:21:03.053  32157-32207/net.motameni.apps.fragments D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

Why?????
I think this is may related to API level (My application API level is 21).
Please see example link and help. Thanks.

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package net.motameni.apps.fragments;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        /**
         * Check the device orientation and act accordingly
         */
        if(config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            //Landscape mode of the device
            LM_Fragment lm_fragment = new LM_Fragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content,lm_fragment);
        }else{
            //Portrait mode of the device
            PM_Fragment pm_fragment = new PM_Fragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content,pm_fragment);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <fragment
        android:name="net.motameni.apps.fragments"
        android:id="@+id/lm_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <fragment
        android:name="net.motameni.apps.fragments"
        android:id="@+id/pm_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**lm_fragment.xml** (same as pm_fragment.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="landscape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**LM_Fragment.java** (same as RM_Fragment):

```
package net.motameni.apps.fragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class LM_Fragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /**
         * Inflate the layout for this fragment
         */
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.lm_fragment,container,false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Put your codes when you add fragments. Probably you have two fragment layouts which is for landscape and portrait with same name which is right. You have error in xml i think.

Comment: Post xml and java code

Comment: i think you copied xml code wrong from tutorial

Comment: I edited my question and add All xml and java files

Comment: i think the problem is that you have set the layout for the activity using   setContentView(), in the MainActivity which is not part of the tutorial. Comment that line of code or remove it.

Comment: Change `android.R.id.content` to `R.id.lm_fragment`

Comment: What is your `minSdkVersion`?

Comment: My minSdkVersion is 10

Answer (score 0):

The tag `fragment` in your xml should be: `Fragment`, it uses
capital letters.

Comment: Oh.. Seriously this cause a problem? Also you can post this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

First, the `name` of `fragment` in `activity_main.xml` should be your `fragment`'s absolute path.In this case, `name` should be `net.motameni.apps.fragments.LM_Fragment`
Second, in the line of `fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content,pm_fragment);`, `R` should be `your-pkg-name.R` but not `android.R`. The former is the `R` you generated while the latter is generated by `Android SDK`.
Third, if you want to add a `pm_fragment`, you need to change your `activity_main.xml` into this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Meanwhile, you need change your code like this:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content,pm_fragment);
```

Most importantly, the `R` is `your-pkg-name.R`

Comment: android.R.id.content gives you the root element of a view, without having to know its actual name/type/ID.

Answer (score 0):

here in your fragment XML :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

you have to add a context to it and change it to :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.blaw.blawblaw">
```

then in your Main XMl :

```
<fragment
        android:name="net.motameni.apps.fragments"
        android:id="@+id/lm_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

you don't have this fragment `"net.motameni.apps.fragments"` ! you should change it to `"com.blaw.blawblaw"` then that fragment show on your page !

and you just need one fragment in your XML , you add two , that's wrong
just add one and then handle fragment changing on your main class !

Best Regard !